# GIT view log merge commits only following a directory

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-log

**Git Beginner Alert!**

I want to get only the merge commits of a repository and filter by a specific directory within the repository.

```
git log -m --date=iso --reverse --format="format:%H|%ad" MY_REMOTE_BRANCH --follow -- my_directory_within_repository
```

Somehow the commits I see doesn't show me the commits only filtered by the directory. It shows for the entire repository.

What am I doing wrong?
Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: `--merges` to select for merge commits; you probably also want to use `--first-parent` since I'm pretty sure you don't care about merges on other branches

Comment: Besides that, I'm not sure: it's possible the refspec you're using for `MY_REMOTE_BRANCH` is off, but `-- directory` is the correct syntax for filtering for commits that change something in `directory/`.

Comment: Additionally : the help for `--follow` says that it only works when tracking a single file.